# iBeacons iOS 7: Is the Bluetooth identifier different from UUID?

Tags: ios7, core-location

The API documentation for Location Awareness states the following under the section Region Monitoring:

> Additionally, if you are ranging an iOS device that has been
>   configured as a beacon, there may be a brief period in which the
>   locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion: method reports two
>   devices(with the same proximity UUID, major, and minor values) instead
>   of just one. This behavior is caused because the Bluetooth identifier
>   of an iOS device changes periodically out of privacy concerns. The
>   proximity property based on the original Bluetooth identifier reports
>   a value of CLProximityUnknown within 2 seconds of the identifier
>   change. Within 10 seconds, the identifiers resolve and only one beacon
>   region is reported.

This seems to suggest that the Bluetooth identifier is different from the UUID. What serves as the bluetooth identifier? How does the receiving device seamlessly handle the change in the identifier?

Does the Bluetooth identifier change over time for custom iBeacon devices (such as estimote beacons)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth identifier is something different than the proximity UUID.
What you see as peripheral's identifier provided by `CoreBluetooth` is a `NSUUID` generated from device's advertised information.

`ProximityUUID` is a part of `iBeacon` advertising packet and has nothing to do with the Bluetooth identifier.

The Bluetooth identifier will change periodically for each device no matter what the device advertises, so yes, if you look for custom iBeacon devices, such as Estimotes,using CoreBluetooth, you will see their UUID (not proximityUUID) change about every 15 minutes.